# Can I skip a specific test when using the race detector?

Tags: testing, go

The Go Race Detector has a goroutine limit of 8192 (at least on my system). One test I run is to see how my server code handles a large number of simultaneous open connections (right now I'm trying out > 15000). When I run `go test --race`, therefore, that particular test fails. I'd rather it be skipped when run using `-race` instead of failing directly. How can I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The build tag `race` is defined when building with the -race flag.

Move the tests you want to exclude to a file with the [build constraint](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Build_constraints) comment:

```
//go:build !race
```

If you are using Go 1.17 or earlier, then include an additional comment with the old build constraint syntax:

```
//go:build !race
// +build !race
```

Comment: Since 1.18, `// +build` is deprecated in favor of `//go:build`: https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.18#go-build-lines. It should now be `//go:build !race`.